# for what region does this Inequality hold

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Am doing an improper integral , and if i can show for some region D that this inequality holds, then I can proceed to solve my problem with comparison test.

$ln(1+2x^{2}+y^{2})\leq \sqrt{(1+x^{2}+y^{2}}$

How to find the region where this hold beyond that region ?

My double integral is over all the plane $R^2$

Thanks in advance

Comment: I noticed you accepted and then unaccepted shortly after, did you find any issue with my answer?

Comment: Fixed , mouse missclick i assume by me or someone else who used my pc, sorry ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the functions $f(r) = \log{(1+2r)}$ and $g(r) = \sqrt{1+r}$. Computing the derivatives, we find that

$$ f'(r) = \frac{2}{1+2r}$$

and

$$ g'(r) = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{1+r}}$$

so for $r > \frac{3}{2} + \sqrt 6$ we have $g'(r) > f'(r)$. We can check that at $r = 0$ and $r = \frac{3}{2} + \sqrt 6$ that $g(r) > f(r),$ so we now know that for all $r \geq 0$,

$$ g(r) > f(r).$$

Note that this also implies that $g(r^2) > f(r^2)$. Thus, we have

$$ \log{(1+2r^2)} \leq \sqrt{1+r^2}.$$

At all points a distance $d$ away from the origin, we have $x^2 + y^2 = d^2$. We conclude

$$ \log{(1 + 2x^2 + y^2)} \leq \log{(1 + 2x^2 + 2y^2)} \leq \sqrt{1+x^2+y^2}$$

for all points $(x,y)$ that are a distance $d$ away from the origin. Since this holds for all $d$, (i.e $g(r^2) > f(r^2)$ for $r \geq 0$) we have established that the inequality holds over the entire plane.